# Ninject MVC3 - how does the type gets resolved

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc

Scenario:
I've set up the Ninject MVC3 using the link below:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Setting-up-an-MVC3-application

I followed Nuget version. And, code looks like below:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IService>().<Service>();
    }
```

Could someone help me to understand when and where does the code below gets excuted?

```
var test=Kernel.Get<Service>();
```

Basically I'm trying to understand where do we resolve the concrete type.

**UPDATE**:

my question is more of where does the MVC use Kernel.Get() to resolve the given Interface to the concrete type.

Is this done by Ninject.MVC?

Comment: I am using a custom controller factory and the contructors of my controllers require parameters of repositories, services etc.

Comment: here are some links http://www.craftyfella.com/2010/02/creating-aspnet-mvc-2-controller.html

Comment: another link https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc

Comment: my question of more of where does the MVC use Kernel.Get<Service>() to resolve the given Interface to the concrete type.

Answer (score 2):

`Kernel.Get<Service>()` shouldn't be called anywhere. You should request an `IService` in the constructor of the controller that needs this dependency. When MVC requires this controller then it asks Ninject to create the controller instance and Ninject will inject the service into the controller.

Comment: +1 @Myagdi some more explicit info: Ninject.MVC3 puts in an `App_Start`, which on startup of the app in IIS tells MVC "use Ninject to create controllers" (which is how the sequence Remo describes becomes possible)